# Altium 3D View not showing properly and Via placement problem

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, routing, via

Can some please tell me how to fix this?
I select all 3D views but every time I get transparent board.
[image]

and when I try to place a via for routing it moves outside of the board.
[image]

need help.....

Comment: Did you figure out the routing on the board? I have the same issue, can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, you're in single-layer mode in the 3D view. Hit Shift S a few times until it goes back to normal.

As for the via issue, it could be a clearance rule (board outline clearance?) that's preventing you from placing the via where you want it. Go into your rules and check that you don't have any undesired restrictions.